# Angle between traces formed by four geografic coordinates

Tags: matlab, geometry, coordinates, coordinate-systems, geography

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esDVq.png)If I have a first trace formed by two coordinates:

```
lat1=-2.760411024093628
lat2=-2.799418926239014
long1=-12.332500457763672
long2=-12.508299827575684
```

and a second trace of the coordinates:

```
lat3=-2.799418926239014
lat4=-2.838399887084961
long3=-12.508299827575684
long4=-12.684100151062012
```

how can I calculate the small geographic angle between the two traces? I would like to apply in some calculation on MATLAB code. I was in double to calculate also

thanks,
Guilherme

I was trying to calculate using the form: a = atan2d(x1*y2-y1*x2,x1*x2+y1*y2);

but it does not works.

Comment: I applied the formula of the other post indicated, but it does not provide an angle close to the triangle's internal angle separating the two traces. I tried to upload an image with a sketch of the map and the three-point, but the webpage does not allow me to show it.

Comment: My current result on MATLAB is: 

>> rad2deg(atan2(sin(abs(stlong_st3)-abs(stlong_st1))*cos(stlat_st3), cos(stlat_st1)*(sin(stlat_st3)-sin(stlat_st1))*cos(stlat_st3)*cos(abs(stlong_st3)-abs(stlong_st1))  ) )
ans =
  89.998875972543047

>> rad2deg(atan2(sin(abs(stlong_st2)-abs(stlong_st1))*cos(stlat_st2), cos(stlat_st1)*(sin(stlat_st2)-sin(stlat_st1))*cos(stlat_st2)*cos(abs(stlong_st2)-abs(stlong_st1))  ) )
ans =
  89.979745488572632

Comment: >> rad2deg(atan2(sin(abs(stlong_st2)-abs(stlong_st3))*cos(stlat_st2), cos(stlat_st3)*(sin(stlat_st2)-sin(stlat_st3))*cos(stlat_st2)*cos(abs(stlong_st3)-abs(stlong_st2))  ) )
ans =
 -89.986424355198139

Comment: Have you transformed  lat/long into radians?

Comment: I have the coordinates in degree. So, I applied the degree coordinates in atan2.

Comment: Arguments of sin and cos should be in radians, so you have to tranform degrees of lat an long to radians (deg2rad)